# Using Swift 3, how can I parse a JSON file so that I can access the data globally?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm a newbie to iOS development, so apologies in advance if I use incorrect terminology. I am working on a basic app for a school project and would appreciate any help!

I have a JSON file with 20 different objects (please see an example of the first object below), which I would like to parse and access in three different View Controllers for different purposes - the same data, just ordered or presented in different ways.

The JSON file is stored locally within the xCode project. How can I parse it so that I may access the data globally within different View Controllers?

My understanding is that it would be best to parse the JSON file in the AppDelegate controller and then call the data within each individual ViewController but I am unsure of how to do this programatically.

The name of the JSON file is "locations.json"

```
{
    locations: [

        {
            "id": 0001,
            "name": "Helensburgh Tunnels",
            "type": ["Tunnels", "Beach", "Views"],
            "location": "Helensburgh, South Coast",
            "image": "Helensburgh-Tunnels.jpg",
            "activity": "Walking, photography, tunnelling",
            "isVisited": false,
            "latitude": -34.178985,
            "longitude": 150.992867
        }
}
```

Then I would appreciate if you could expand upon how I may read this data in a TableView. My TableView cells are currently configured as below (reading out of an array which is hard coded into the same ViewController) - how can I update this to read the parsed JSON data?

Name of ViewController; LocationTableViewController.swift

```
var locations:[Location] = [
        Location(name: "Helensburgh Tunnels", type: "Old, abandoned train tunnels.", location: "Helensburgh, South Coast", image: "Helensburgh-Tunnels.jpg", activity: "Walking, photography, tunnelling", isVisited: false, latitude: "-34.178985", longitude: "150.992867")
]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.nameLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row].name
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: locations[indexPath.row].image)
    cell.locationLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row].location
    cell.typeLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row].type
    cell.accessoryType = locations[indexPath.row].isVisited ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

The location model is as follows.
Name of ViewController; Location.swift

```
class Location: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var name: String = ""
    var type: String = ""
    var location: String = ""
    var image: String = ""
    var activity: String = ""
    var isVisited: Bool = false
    var rating: String = ""
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0

    init(name: String, type: String, location: String, image: String, activity: String, isVisited: Bool, latitude: String, longitude: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.location = location
        self.image = image
        self.activity = activity
        self.isVisited = isVisited
        self.latitude = Double(latitude)!
        self.longitude = Double(longitude)!
    }

    public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        return coordinate
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can create a model class and parse the JSON file there so that you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Swift File like GlobalClass.Swift

import Foundation and UIKit in GlobalClass
make function to read location like this:-

```
func readLocation() ->[String:Any]?{
    do {
        if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "locations", withExtension: "json") {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.mutableContainers])
            if let object = json as? [String: Any] {
                return object
            }
            return nil
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

and call this function from TableView like this:-

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        if let locationJson = readLocation(){
            if let locations = locationJson["location"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                cell.nameLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row]["name"] as! String
                cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: (locations[indexPath.row]["image"] as! String))
                cell.locationLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row]["location"] as! String
                cell.typeLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row]["type"] as! String
                cell.accessoryType = (locations[indexPath.row]["isVisited"] as! Bool) ? .checkmark : .none
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

and number of rows in section should be

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let locationJson = readLocation(){
            if let locations = locationJson["location"] as? [[String:Any]]{
              return   locations.count
        }
    }
  return 0
}
```

Make sure your location file should be in correct json format otherwise this function throw an error

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good option. Could you please expand upon how to call the data in other view controllers? For example, how to read it into a TableView?

Comment: you can call like this from any where even in tableView cell you can call

Comment: if let location = readLocation(){
            print("Location JSON :",location)
           // do what ever you want
        }

Comment: I have edited the question to include additional information about my table cells. Could you please provide more detail on your answer?

Comment: i am updating my answer please look at this

Comment: Would there be a way to read all the data at the top of the ViewController in a variable array?
var locations:[Location] = []

Comment: @joshlorschy share your location model and whole view controller code with tableview code

Comment: i made a demo for you download demo project from below link

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my issues completely and allowed me to easily emulate your solution into my own project.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't normally look at the AppDelegate for this type of thing. You should do as little there as possible,

You may want to look at an [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)-like approach. You could create a viewmodel whose job is to vend out the various permutations of the data. You could create this as a singleton, but if your app isn't too complex you could simply instantiate the viewmodel in each of your view controllers.

I generally write a data manager which is responsible for parsing the data and provides a method to retrieve the data as an array of models. The viewmodel can call the datamanager method when it is instantiated or as needed. Again, for simple projects you could do the data parsing directly in the viewmodel. The viewmodel would have various methods that the view controllers would use to retrieve the data in the necessary format.

The above is heavily simplified, but should work for your needs.

Basic flow:

1. View controller(s) instantiates the viewmodel (or gets a shared instance) and calls a method on the viewmodel
2. Viewmodel calls method on datamanager if it doesn't already have data.
3. Datamanager parses JSON and returns array of models
4. Viewmodel method manipulates data from models (e.g. sorting) and returns them to the view controller.
5. View controller presents the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

**Read content from file & create a dictionary**

```
let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "txt")

let url = URL(string: urlString!)

if let url = url {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

        let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[])

        // Model creation code here.
    } catch {
        print("Error : ")
    }
}
```

From `jsonDictionary` object you construct your model classes. **Please refer the [link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) for, How to parse the json objects and store it in model classes.**

**Model :**

```
struct LocationDetails {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    // Other variables are here
}
```

**Manager Class :**

```
// Here you can store common properties.
class AppUtils {
    class var parsedResponse: [LocationDetails]
}
```

After constructed the models list. For example `[LocationDetails]`. You have to store it in the `AppUtils` class `parsedResponse` variable.

```
var locationDetailsList =  [LocationDetails]()
//Your model construction code here.

//Store the array of objects into AppUtils class
AppUtils.parsedResponse = locationDetailsList
```

Access the models on different `UIViewController` like this.

```
AppUtils.parsedResponse
```

***NOTE : If your app is not accessing the data then don't keep the values always on memory. Try to clean up the memory whenever possible.***

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I'm very new to coding, so where would I implement all of this code?